# Any yahoo messenger lib for python?

Tags: python, yahoo-messenger

Is there any lib available to connect to yahoo messenger using either the standard protocol or the http way from python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google is your friend.

The [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) has [several](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=yahoo&submit=search) modules to do with Yahoo, including this [one](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahoolib/0.2) which matches your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Yahoo IM SDK](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/index.html) that might help.

Comment: i ended up rolling my own implementation based on libpurple http://code.google.com/p/ymsg/